# How to hide URL parameters in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

When a user is creating a new `Load` object, if the user checks the "Paid On Delivery" check box then they will be redirected to the `Payment` controller immediately after the new `Load` has been created.  Several of the parameters needed to create a new `Load` are also used to create a new `Payment`, so I just pass the parameters in the redirect like this:

```
redirect(controller: "payment", action: "create", params: params)
```

This works fine, but it gives me a real nasty URL with all the parameters in it.  **How can I pass my parameters to another controller and keep them from appearing in the URL?**

**UPDATE:**

I should say that I appreciate everyone's suggestions for such a little problem.  Even with all the suggestions, it still seems the best way of doing this is the way I wanted to avoid, building the parameter map manually in the `redirect` call.  It isn't that big of a deal, especially since there is only a few params, I just don't believe there is isn't a cleaner more automated way of fixing this.

```
    def loadInstance = new Load(params)

    if (loadInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        Account.get(params.account.id).balance -= new BigDecimal(params.transactionAmount) 
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'load.label', default: 'Load'), loadInstance.id])}"
        if(params.paidOnDelivery){
            redirect(
                controller: "payment",
                action: "create",

                //There has to be a better way than this. Just writing "params:params" results in the values being wrapped in double quotes once they get to the Payment controller. If it wasn't for that then "params:params" would work great and I would not of had to ask this question :)
                params: [
                    "account.id":params.account.id,
                    "dateOfTransaction":params.dateOfTransaction,
                    "dateOfTransaction_year":params.dateOfTransaction_year,
                    "dateOfTransaction_month":params.dateOfTransaction_month,
                    "dateOfTransaction_day":params.dateOfTransaction_day,
                    "dateOfTransaction_hour":params.dateOfTransaction_hour,
                    "dateOfTransaction_minute":params.dateOfTransaction_minute,
                    "transactionAmount":params.transactionAmount
                ]
            ) 
            return
        }
        redirect(action: "show", id: loadInstance.id)
    }
    else {
        render(view: "create", model: [loggedByUsers:loggedByUsers, accounts:accounts, cargoProviders:cargoProviders, deliveredByUsers:deliveredByUsers, loadInstance:loadInstance])
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do a server-side forward instead of a redirect. Simply replace:

```
redirect(controller: "payment", action: "create", params: params)
```

with:

```
forward(controller: "payment", action: "create", params: params)
```

### Update

To fix the refresh problem you described in the comments, make the action that you forward to sends a redirect (instead of rendering a view), e.g.

```
class PaymentController {

  def create = {

    Integer paymentId = // Create a payment and get it's ID    
    redirect(action: 'show', id: paymentId)    
  }

  def show = {
    def id = params.id
    // show the payment with this ID
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems this solution makes the refresh button virtually unusable. Every time I press the refresh button after the forward a new Load is created if I press "Resend" in the "Resend"/"Cancel" box that pops up.  I noticed that even after the forward, the URL still shows the `Load` controller as the active controller instead of the `Payment` controller. Thanks for the reply, but unless I can iron these issues out (especially the refresh button functionality) I don't think this will work.

Comment: The redirect needs to happen in `save` action of my `Load` controller. The redirect is going to the `create` action of my `Payment` controller, and the view returned from that `create` action is `.../payment/create`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Pass them via session parameters

or

1. Make the HTTP request server-side instead of a redirect and then just render the result to the client

Comment: It seems that using session parameters would be better than using the flash scope except it is difficult to remove the session parameters at the right time. I don't want those parameters hanging around in the session after a user leaves the page, but I do want them there if a user just presses the refresh button. I don't know how to work around this. This dilemma is easy to remedy when using the flash scope.  Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a before and after filter possibility. You could strip all of your show-once vars in a before filter -- that way the previous request's vars are removed and you can still set new ones for display during this request. Although I would imagine that is something that the flash scope already does :)

Answer (score 1):

The flash object can be used to achieve this (although I would leave the implementation as is).

Copy all your params to flash.

```
params.each {
  flash[it.key]=it.value
}
```

Use the flash map instead of params map in the 'create' action.

Comment: It works, but doesn't feel right, and I also had to do some other finagling. In the payment controller I had to check to see if the the parameters were actually stored in the flash scope so `params` was not unnecessarily overridden: `params.putAll((flash.transactionAmount) ? flash : params)`. I then had to add some jQuery to my `/payment/create` view because for some reason certain fields were erased if the user didn't make a change to the field before pressing the refresh button. jQuery `trigger('change')` didn't work, but reading the value then re-setting it did.

Comment: Also, just putting `flash.params = params` works just as well :)

Answer (score 0):

i didn't try it but i think it will solve your problem.

```
redirect(controller: "payment", action = [POST:"create"], params: params)
```

Comment: I had looked into POST, but redirect seems to default to GET. This didn't work for me, nor did the other solutions that I looked at that tried to change the redirect method from GET to POST. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion :-)

Keep the redirect from Load to Payment as is. Check in Payment action if you receive a call with params, then save those in session or flash and redirect to same action without params. Restore params from session/flash using putAll and proceed with action.

Kind of like a Post-Redirect-Get in Payment, but actually a GetWithParams-Redirect-Get. Results in clean URL and no Refresh problems.

I use it in a app for clean URLs and for keeping states in different parts of the app (but since you don't need the latter you should remove it or keep it in flash).